No puedo ejecutar deno en vscode
he estado probando deno en mi ordenador instalándolo y tal, y cuando voy a ejecutar el comando de
deno run --allow-net filename.ts

en la terminal de vscode, me aparece un error diciendo que:
"deno : El término 'deno' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre
o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo."
Lo he instalado todo correctamente y en la terminal de powershell si que me funciona el comando deno, no se porque en vscode no me funciona. He probado poniendo la ruta del ejecutable en las variables de entorno, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Probaste a reiniciar VSC?? Las variables de entorno las coge al abrirse, si instalaste deno pero no reiniciaste vsc es posible que no tenga el path actualizado

cómo sabes que lo insalaste correctamente? por lo que dices parece que no tienes configurado deno en tu variable PATH. Igual sería bueno que especificaras el sistema operativo. ¿En la consola de tu sistema operativo si funciona o cómo estás seguro que es un problema del vscode?

This question is similar to: Problema al crear proyecto en Django. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
